# I am trying to replace an image with the other one by using javascript but it isn't working.I am new to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
body
{
    background-image: url("background-test.gif");
}
h1
{
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: geneva;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px red;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h2
{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: geneva;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px red;
    text-align: center;
}
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a h3
{
    font-family: geneva;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: 650px;
    
}
#computer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 100px;
}
#user
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}
#versus
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 280px;
    left: 600px;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px gray;
    font-size: 120px;
    
}
#msg
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 100px;
}
#stone
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 200px;
}
#paper
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 300px;
}
#scissors
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 400px;
}
```

I am trying to change the image user.png by clicking on the image stone.png which on clicking calls the function change() but the function is not replacing the image,however i checked whether the function is getting called or not and i found that it is getting called it is just not replacing the image.

```js
function change()
{

     if(document.getElementbyId('stone').clicked == true)
     {
         document.getElementbyId('user').src="stone2.jpg"
     }

}
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id="computer" src="computer.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<h1 id="versus"> Vs </h1>
<img id="user" src="user.png" width="400" height="400">
<h2 id="msg"> Choose your option !! </h2>
<a href="" onClick="change()"> <img id="stone" src="stone.png" width="70" height="70"></a>
<a href="" onClick="change()"> <img id="paper" src="paper.jpg" width="70" height="70"></a>
<a href="" onClick="change()"> <img id="scissors" src="scissors.jpg" width="70" height="70"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscode.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `clicked` property of an element. Remove the `if` condition. See the duplicate for more information and some examples

Comment: but in the code there's a option to choose between 3 images and each of them calls the function change() so in that function i am checking which image is clicked for that i added if condition and even as per your advice i tried removing if condition but still it didn't work.

Comment: This is the equivalence of what you're tying to achieve         function change()
{
  document.getElementById('stone').addEventListener('clicked',()=>{
    document.getElementbyId('user').src="stone2.jpg"
  })

}

Comment: In that case you need to determine which element was clicked,either by using separate event handlers, or passing an argument to the function

Comment: @Eric I tried this but it is not working,please help me in any other possible way if you can.

Comment: check this solution https://codepen.io/Baron14/pen/NWxMMLa?editors=1010

Comment: @Eric It worked,thankyou so much for your help.This was my first experience on stackoverflow and it turned out to be so helpful and amazing.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)